# SQL workbench This connection has been closed in few minutes

Tags: postgresql, sql-workbench-j

I use SQL workbench to connect postgresql. But I frequently get following error

```
This connection has been closed.
```

when ever I kept the window idle for 2-3 minutes.

I am not sure where to the change the settings. Please help me .

Version  : Build 118.7

Comment: That has nothing to do with SQL Workbench - your Postgres server closes the connections.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : How to keep the session alive for long ?

Answer (score 1):

If the server is configured to disconnect idle connections, you can configure a statement that is sent to the database server in regular intervals.

This is done in the connection profile. Click on the "Connect scripts" button:

[Connection dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62NMH.png)

Then enter a statement for "Statement to keep connection alive".

[Connect scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNlDn.png)

In the "Idle time" you can configure how often the statement should be executed. "1m" means that it's run every minute unless you run statements manually (or do something in the DbExplorer)

This should prevent the server to disconnect your session.